# Exact differential forms defined in path connected sets

Tags: analysis, differential-forms, connectedness

There's a theorem in mathematics that states:

> Let $A$ be an open path connected set in $\mathbb{R^m}$, and $\omega:A\to\mathbb{R^{1\times2}},x\to[\omega^1(x)\space...\space \omega^m]$ be a 1 degree differential form, then $\omega$ is exact.

But we know that:
$$\omega:\mathbb{R^2\setminus \{(0,0)}\}\to \mathbb{R^{1\times2}}\\(x,y)\to\bigg[ -\dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2} \space\ \dfrac{x}{x^2 +y^2}\bigg]$$

is not an exact differential form, however, $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is an path connected set. What am I getting wrong?

PS:I may be a bit lost in translation about some technical terms, and some rigor may also be flawed, but I hope the message gets through.

Comment: Your "theorem" is wrong and the counter-example is correct. The statement becomes correct if you assume that $A$ is simply connected.

Comment: Just looked up the definitions for arc and path connected sets and I meant a path connected set (already edited it), is it still wrong?

Comment: Yes, to my knoweldge both path and arc connected mean the same (if $A$ is open it's equivalent to ask that $A$ is connected). You need a stronger assumption which is simply connected, look here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space

Comment: what would then be the theorem regarding the set in which the differential form is defined and its exactness?

Comment: The theorem is as follows (and it's usually called the Poincaré lemma) : let $A$ be a simply connected open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Then, any closed $1$-form on $A$ is exact.

Comment: P.S : I didn't noticed something but in fact your version as stated is also wrong : you need to assume that $\omega$ is closed, because it's a necessary condition to be exact.